# while (double?) foreach or join?

Tags: php, mysql, join, foreach, while-loop

I have an Excel sheet which is converted to csv and then code imports that into mysql.
In Excel I have in first row A's and B's

I get output, It works but I cannot get into displaying data right.

> **How I'm trying to display is A B then break and again A B and so on**. It is ordered by contact_id but I only get AAAAAA's and 1 B if I try double while.

This is the code with which I have tried to achieve this. Tried double while and I have googled and I have noticed double while is not working, Couldn't get it to work with mysql JOIN either and have never worked with foreach function.

```
$data = dbquery("SELECT contact_id, contact_first, contact_last, contact_email FROM contact_info WHERE contact_first='A)' ORDER BY contact_id ASC");
$data2 = dbquery("SELECT contact_id, contact_first, contact_last, contact_email FROM contact_info WHERE contact_first='B)' ORDER BY contact_id ASC");


    while ($userdata = dbarray($data)) {


   echo "<li><ul class='ulcla'>";
   echo "<h1>".$userdata['contact_first']."</h1>"; 
   echo "<li>".$userdata['contact_last']."</li>";
   echo "</ul><br>";
   while ($userdata = dbarray($data2)) {
   echo "".$userdata['contact_id']." - ".$userdata2['contact_first']." - ".$userdata2['contact_last']." - ".$userdata2['contact_email']."";
   echo "<br>"; 
    }
    echo "</ol></div>";   

      }
```

How could I loop data like that?

Comment: can you share the a CSV record for clarity?

Comment: nested `while` and nested `foreach` don't differ much.

Comment: it's quite hard to work out what you're trying to do from the question, but your two queries are using exactly the same SQL string, which looks very wrong. Even if you want to loop the same data inside itself, there are ways to achieve it without querying the same data twice.

Comment: changed first $data to where A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  `while ($userdata = dbarray($data2)) {` to  `while ($userdata2 = dbarray($data2)) {`for innner while loop

```
$data = dbquery("SELECT contact_id, contact_first, contact_last, contact_email FROM contact_info WHERE contact_first='B)' ORDER BY contact_id ASC");
$data2 = dbquery("SELECT contact_id, contact_first, contact_last, contact_email FROM contact_info WHERE contact_first='B)' ORDER BY contact_id ASC");


    while ($userdata = dbarray($data)) {


   echo "<li><ul class='ulcla'>";
   echo "<h1>".$userdata['contact_first']."</h1>"; 
   echo "<li>".$userdata['contact_last']."</li>";
   echo "</ul><br>";
   while ($userdata2 = dbarray($data2)) {
   echo "".$userdata2['contact_id']." - ".$userdata2['contact_first']." - ".$userdata2['contact_last']." - ".$userdata2['contact_email']."";
   echo "<br>"; 
    }
    echo "</ol></div>";   

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are the same amount of each A and B then you can create two arrays from the output and use a simple for loop to go through the keys. So it could echo $userdata[$x] and $userdata2[$x] where $x is the loop iterator.

Try to avoid using multiple loops, especially nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($userdata = dbarray($data)) {
    //your stuff
    while ($other_userdata = dbarray($data2)) {
        //your other stuff
    }
}
```